# JQuery button won't click

Tags: jquery, html

Alright, I've looked everywhere on StackOverflow but can't find an answer. I have html that looks like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Sign Up Here" id="buttonClick">
```

and a script at the top that says

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#buttonClick").click(function(){
    alert("hello");
  )};
)};
```

But the alert never shows. It's just a test alert to try to get the click to work, as the rest should be fine. Any ideas?

Comment: you missed id selector '#'... should be $("#buttonClick").click... !

Comment: As posted below, a type on my part. I apologize. I have the selector, and nothing works.

Comment: the page you linked dont have jquery.js loaded. You need to add jquery.js file as your script source prior to trying to use any of its methods.... along with that you have invalid html in the same page (might not be the cause of your current issue but you should know that)

Comment: You, sir, get the gold star! Totally forgot about that. Included it in my other file, but not this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**You are missing the selector in jQuery**. Since you have an id for the button, you should use `#`(id) selector.

Read more about selectors in the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

**Also your closing brackets in the javascript are not correct. It has to be `});` instead of `)};`.**

Thus, Replace

```
$("buttonClick").click(function(){
    alert("hello");
  )};
)};
```

with

```
$("#buttonClick").click(function(){
    alert("hello");
  });
});
```

Please see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/mecqwrdp/)

Comment: Ah. Simple typo when pulling over (ssh won't let me copy right now). I do indeed have the selector. As with the brackets. Apologies. Don't want to waste your time. Edited.

Comment: Notice the closing brackets

Comment: Still not working. Identical to the Fiddle though. Hmmmmm.

Comment: Nope. Nothing. Very puzzling.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to add the JQuery.min.js script at the beginning. Fixed!

Comment: Please mark your answer as Accepted solution. As it makes this post a complete one .. :)

Comment: Can't yet. Have to wait two days. Will do!